# WKWebView content not loading on iOS 12.4.8 (physical device)

Tags: html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an issue loading HTML content inside WKWebView only on 12.4.8 iOS version.

Here is the configuration:

```
    private lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    let web = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    return web
}()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadWebViewContent()
}

private func loadWebViewContent() { 
     guard let filename = ZippedCalculatorsDefaults.filename else { return }
     var htmlURL = DocumentsDirectoryManager.shared.path.appendingPathComponent(filename).appendingPathComponent("index").appendingPathExtension("html")
     htmlURL = URL(string: "#\(item.alias)", relativeTo: htmlURL)!
     webView.loadFileURL(htmlURL, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlURL)
}
```

It all works on any iOS version above 12.4, and there is also lack of normal logs in Xcode console.
Only logs are:

> 2021-02-26 17:04:59.399986+0400 MultiDoc[571:40553] *** Assertion
> failure in -[_CUIPDFRendition _initWithCSIHeader:],
> /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI/CoreUI-499.12/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition.m:2392
> 2021-02-26 17:04:59.400326+0400 MultiDoc[571:40553] [framework]
> -[CUIThemeRendition initWithCSIData:forKey:artworkStatus:] got exception 'CoreUI: -[_CUIPDFRendition _initWithCSIHeader:] pixel
> format must be kCSIPixelFormatPDF' 2021-02-26 17:04:59.400490+0400
> MultiDoc[571:40553] *** Assertion failure in -[_CUIPDFRendition
> _initWithCSIHeader:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI/CoreUI-499.12/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition.m:2392
> 2021-02-26 17:04:59.400652+0400 MultiDoc[571:40553] [framework]
> -[CUIThemeRendition initWithCSIData:forKey:artworkStatus:] got exception 'CoreUI: -[_CUIPDFRendition _initWithCSIHeader:] pixel
> format must be kCSIPixelFormatPDF' 2021-02-26 17:04:59.401945+0400
> MultiDoc[571:40553] *** Assertion failure in -[_CUIPDFRendition
> _initWithCSIHeader:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI/CoreUI-499.12/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition.m:2392
> 2021-02-26 17:04:59.404685+0400 MultiDoc[571:40553] [framework]
> -[CUIThemeRendition initWithCSIData:forKey:artworkStatus:] got exception 'CoreUI: -[_CUIPDFRendition _initWithCSIHeader:] pixel
> format must be kCSIPixelFormatPDF' 2021-02-26 17:04:59.404924+0400
> MultiDoc[571:40553] *** Assertion failure in -[_CUIPDFRendition
> _initWithCSIHeader:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI/CoreUI-499.12/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition.m:2392
> 2021-02-26 17:04:59.405087+0400 MultiDoc[571:40553] [framework]
> -[CUIThemeRendition initWithCSIData:forKey:artworkStatus:] got exception 'CoreUI: -[_CUIPDFRendition _initWithCSIHeader:] pixel
> format must be kCSIPixelFormatPDF'

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please share url

Comment: Are you trying to load ".svg" files ? SVG's are supported natively from iOS 13.